# PHP setting nested object property with string literal

Tags: php, string, object, properties

$person is an object which has the property 'name' which has the property 'first'. Can I access the property 'first' from top level $person with a single string literal?

I've tried,

```
$prop='name->first';
$person->$prop;

$prop='name->first';
$person->{$prop};
```

Neither of these evaluate the '->' in the string to get the name property 'first' from 'name'.

I could explode the string into an array, but I was hoping not to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do like this, but [eval](http://www.php.net/eval) is almost always a bad idea:

```
$prop='name->first';
$result = eval("\$result = \$person->$prop");
```

Comment: Eval does have quite a few concerns/drawbacks, but it does work for this.

Comment: Can't seem to find an alternative, so this is getting the checkmark. If anybody has a better way, comment away.